# How to store checkbox and array values (cookies)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I want to save the boolean values of my checkbox for a longer period. Also I need to store the values of each checkbox in an array to read them out later. I´ve tried some example code and tutorials about cookies but nothing seems to work.

With checklist_1s.html i access checklistRequest.js to store the values of each checkbox in my array. Later I´ll need to use this array for another js function in another window, but the moment I open this window, my array is gone.

I´m looking for an easy solution here, if possible.

Note: I know using the same name for every checkbox is an violation, but it seems to work so far and I couldn´t find any other way to get it to work for every checkbox (I´ll need like 200 later)

**checklist_1s.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../style.css"></link>
<script src="checklistRequest.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.github.com/andris9/jStorage/master/jstorage.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.cookie/1.4.0/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body class="main">
<div class="main_2">
    <p>
        <h1>Checklist</h1>

        <form>
            <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" onclick="checkboxFunction(value, 0)" value="F-Card geholt">F-Card geholt<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" onclick="checkboxFunction(value, 1)" value="Ersti Rally">Ersti Rally <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" onclick="checkboxFunction(value, 2)" value="TEST">TEST<br>
        </form>

        <input type="button" name="alert" value="Aktualisieren" onclick="alertFunction()">



        <!-- Example Code-->
        <script>
          $("#checkAll").on("change", function(){
            $(':checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
          });

          $(":checkbox").on("change", function(){
            var checkboxValues = {};
            $(":checkbox").each(function(){
              checkboxValues[this.id] = this.checked;
            });
            $.cookie('checkboxValues', checkboxValues, { expires: 7, path: '/' })
          });

          function repopulateCheckboxes(){
            var checkboxValues = $.cookie('checkboxValues');
            if(checkboxValues){
              Object.keys(checkboxValues).forEach(function(element){
                var checked = checkboxValues[element];
                $("#" + element).prop('checked', checked);
              });
            }
          }

          $.cookie.json = true;
          repopulateCheckboxes();
        </script>

    </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**checklistRequest.js**

```
var checkbox = document.getElementsByName("remember");
var checkboxArray = [];

function checkboxFunction(value, index)
{
    if(checkbox[index].checked == true)
    {
        checkboxArray[index] = value;
    }
    if (checkbox[index].checked == false && value == checkboxArray[index])
    {
        checkboxArray[index] = null;
    }
}

function alertFunction()
{
    for(var i=0; i<99; i++)
    {
        if (typeof checkboxArray[i] != 'undefined' && checkboxArray[i] != null) 
        {
            alert(checkboxArray[i]); 
        }
    }  
    alert("TEST");  
}
```

Comment: Html5 localStorage maybe will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. It still won´t save if the checkbox is checked, but that shouldn´t be a problem now.